# Can I replace items in string based off of an array using vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I'm using a helper function to replace all the instances of a word in a string with a "-". I would like to search an array and replace any instance from the array. Below is the current snippet that can only replace on string at a time.

```
let x = document.querySelector("form.form").elements;
    let input = x["formName"].value;

        function replaceAll(string, search, replace) {
          return string.split(search).join(replace);
          }


    let noStop = replaceAll(input, "example", "-");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with regex. You need to use **OR** `|` and the **global** flag, `g`, which matches all the possible matches, essentially turning `replace(regex)` to `replaceAll`.

```js
let words = ['hi','hello','dear']
let regex = new RegExp(words.join('|'), 'g') //  /hi|hello|dear/g

let string = 'hi dear, are you there?, hello?'
let result = string.replace(regex, '-')

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map()` to call a function on every element of an array.

```
newArray = oldArray.map(s => s.replaceAll(search, replace));
```

Notice that there's a built-in [`replaceAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll) method, you don't need to write your own function.

Comment: Could be wrong, but I think OP wants something like `['itemtoreplace','itemtoreplace'].forEach(s => input.replaceAll(s, "-"))`

Comment: You're right, I thought he was talking about the array returned by `split()`.

Comment: Hi! Your answer is perfect, but I prefer your original post to the current one. Would it be possible to describe `.replaceAll()`/`.replace(regex)` with example code following `.map()`? It would be so helpful for OP. Thank you.

Comment: What's to describe? It does exactly what your `replaceAll()` function does. And I linked to the documentation that explains it in detail.

Comment: My original answer didn't answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for the input. The built-in replaceAll doesn't allow for an array or variable, and I was hoping using the function would allow me to do that.

Comment: No, that's why you have to use `map()`. It's the general way to run the same function on every element of an array.